# Sqlite : How many parameters can there be in an 'in' clause

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I'd like to perform the following:

```
delete from images where image_address not in (<a long list>)
```

How long can this list be? (I'm guessing I might have to think of another way).

Comment: Do you get that list from the DB too?

Comment: Actually I was planning to pass it in, although I could make a table

Comment: parenthesis should contain coloun names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using parameters (`?`), [the maximum number is 999 by default](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_variable_number).

If you are creating the SQL statement dynamically by inserting the values directly (which is a bad thing to do for strings), there is no upper limit on the lenght of such a list. However, there is [a limit on the length of the entire SQL statement](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_sql_length), which is one million bytes by default.

If you cannot guarantee that your query does not exceed these limits, you must use a temporary table (see LS_dev's answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a long list, I would suggest two approaches:

First solution:

Add all data to temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE lng_list(image_address);
-- Insert all you elements in lng_list table
-- ...
DELETE FROM images WHERE image_address NOT IN (SELECT image_address FROM lng_list);
```

Make sure to use this inside transaction to get good performace.

Second solution:

(REMOVED: only works for `IN`, not `NOT IN`...)

Performance should be fair good for any of those solutions.

Comment: Thanks @LS_dev - you're solution was helpful. (Accepted CL because he answered the other part of the question too).